# EmguCV ImageGrabbed event not firing

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls, emgucv

I wrote a small program for displaying a webcam on a WPF Image component. There was such a problem, the Capture_ImageGrabbed event is not called. I can’t understand why this happens, because before that I wrote exactly the same code for a WPF application but without a UserControl.

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using Emgu.CV;
using DirectShowLib;
using System.Windows.Threading;
using ClassLibrary2;

namespace VideoChat
{
    public partial class WebCamUserControl : UserControl
    {
        private VideoCapture capture = null;
        private DsDevice[] webCams;
        private int selectedCameraId = 0;
        public WebCamUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            webCams = DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            if (webCams.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (var camera in webCams)
                {
                    WebCamList.Items.Add(camera.Name);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Камеры не обнаружены.");
                return;
            }
        }

        private void TurnOnWebCam_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (webCams.Length == 0)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Нет доступных камер!");
                }
                else if (WebCamList.SelectedItem == null)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Необходимо выбрать камеру!");
                }

                StopWebCam();
                capture = new VideoCapture(selectedCameraId);
                **capture.ImageGrabbed += Capture_ImageGrabbed; //does not work**
                capture.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
        }

**        private void Capture_ImageGrabbed(object? sender, EventArgs e) //does not work
        {
            try
            {
                Mat mat = new Mat();
                capture.Retrieve(mat);
                BitmapSource image = mat.ToBitmapSource();
                Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { WebCamImage.Source = image; });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Ошибка!", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                return;
            }
        }**

        private void StopWebCam()
        {
            if (capture != null)
            {
                capture.Stop();
                capture = null;
            }
        }

        private void WebCamList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            selectedCameraId = WebCamList.SelectedIndex;
        }
    }
}
```

Before that, I created the same application but without using the UserControl. Could this be a mistake?